# Spacy - English language model outruns german language model on german text?

Tags: spacy

Is it by design that the english language model performs better on german salution entities than the german model?

```
# pip install spacy
# python -m spacy download en
# python -m spacy download de

nlp = spacy.load('en')
# Uncomment line below to get less good results
# nlp = spacy.load('de')

# Process text
text = (u"Das Auto kauft Herr Müller oder Frau Meier, Frank Muster")
doc = nlp(text)

# Find named entities
for entity in doc.ents:
    print(entity.text, entity.label_)
```

**expected** result if using `nlp = spacy.load('en')`. All three PERSON is returned

```
Das Auto ORG
Herr Müller PERSON
Frau Meier PERSON
Frank Muster PERSON
```

**unexpected** result if using `nlp = spacy.load('de')`. Only one of three PERSON is returned

```
Frank Muster PERSON
```

---

**Info about spaCy**

- spaCy version:** 2.0.12
- Platform:** Linux-4.17.2-1-ARCH-x86_64-with-arch-Arch-Linux
- Python version:** 3.6.5
- Models:** en, de

Answer (score 2):

It's not by design, but it's certainly possible that this is a side-effect of the training data and the statistical predictions. The [English model](https://spacy.io/models/en) is trained on a larger NER corpus with more entity types, while the [German model](https://spacy.io/models/de) uses NER data based on Wikipedia.

In Wikipedia text, full names like "Frank Muster" are quite common, whereas things like "Herr Muster" are typically avoided. This might explain why the model only labels the full name as a person and not the others. The example sentence also makes it easy for the English model to guess correctly – in English,  capitalization is a much stronger indicator of a named entity than it is in German. This might explain why the model consistently labels all capitalised multi-word spans as entities.

In any case, this is a good example of how subtle language-specific or stylistic conventions end up influencing a model's predictions. It also shows why you almost always want to fine-tune a model with more examples specific to your data. I do think that the German model will likely perform better on German texts *overall*, but if references like "Herr Müller" are common in your texts, you probably want to update the model with more examples of them in different contexts.